# Google Cloud Deployment File

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I'm trying to deploy to Google Cloud, Flex env, Python 3.

Deployment takes forever (~1 Hour), and gives me a 502 when it finally deploys.

The actual part where something is happening takes about 5 minutes, then it sits on "Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)" for quite a while.

I do see an error about ALLOWED_HOSTS, even though I've specified ['*'] for allowed hosts.

I can't find a single 502 in the logs.  I've followed the samples, etc.  I've tried everything I can think of for several days.

This is my app.yml:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT myapp.application

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: /.*
  script: myapp.application

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

Comment: Is this really a python question?

Comment: Yes, it's a python app that works great locally but not deployed.

Comment: Needs google cloud tag

Comment: Can you share the exact error about *ALLOWED_HOSTS* you mentioned?

Comment: 2017-12-19 08:47:14 default[20171215t175304]  Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '10.128.0.9'. You may need to add '10.128.0.9' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

It's one of these every second or so.